# How to get ALB name from AWS in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I need to get an ALB name or id to attach WAF rules to it.
The ALB is created by Kubernetes and not used anywhere in Terraform.
Oficial data resource only supports name and arn with no filtering.

```
data "aws_lb" "test" {
  name = ...
  arn = ...
}
```

Is there a way to get ALB somehow or attach WAF rules to it?

Comment: Did you create `Kubernetes` cluster outside of terraform?

Comment: @Marcin, yes I have used helm.

Comment: Can you please show the code for that?

Comment: @Marcin, sorry, I meant ALB is deployed via LB controller inside of the EKS cluster.  The controller is deployed to the cluster via helm charts.  This controller looks for specific annotation on ingress and ALB on AWS through the service account which can handle AWS provisioning. More on it [here](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/latest/). Basically, Kubernetes handles AWS deployment on AWS, and there is no way to get this ALB in Terraform because lb module does not have a filter.

Comment: I thought It was Classic LB and WAF does not support Classic LB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently facing the same issue, the name of the ALB doesn't appear to be something that you can set whilst you're deploying the Helm chart and there doesn't appear to be a way of getting the name once the chart has been deployed.

The only workaround I can think of is to describe the ingress resource and then do a trim of some sort on the ingress address using Terraform (ignoring everything after the 4th dash).

It's not a great workaround but is the only one that I've come up with to get this all working through Terraform. Do let me know if you find a better solution for this.

EDIT: It appears that there is already an open issue for this on GitHub: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/12265 There is a solution posted a bit further down in the thread which is similar to what I had originally suggested - using regex to get the name of the load balancer from the ingress resource.

Comment: Yes, that should work.
It does not work for me since I cant get access to the cluster from the place I use tf. I end up using the values store. I will post under.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go in reversed route and had to store the value of WAF rule in the value store.

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "whatever" {
  name  = "...."
  type  = "SecureString"
  value = aws_wafv2_web_acl.name.arn
  overwrite = true
}
```

And then template it into helm chart annotation: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/latest/guide/ingress/annotations/#addons
with gomplate: https://docs.gomplate.ca/datasources/#examples where it will attach the rule to the created ALB.